# Visual Studio 2008 - Compile problem

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am getting this error msg:

> Error 1 It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. C:\LODE\Web\web.config 21

I checked IIS on my XP machine and it is configured as an application. How can I fix that problem?

Thank you.

Steve

Comment: Is this a server configuration issue? If so, it belongs on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: I don't think it is a server configuration error.

Comment: By the way, it's an XP machine with IIS 5.1. I do not have a second web.config folder...

Comment: Nobody has any suggestions? I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You could to either change that to allowDefinition="Everywhere", or create independent 
application ASP/ASP.NET in ~/appcat/